# What's the proportion of powers of 3 to power of 6 in first n integers? Or rather, the amount of powers of 6 or 3 in respect to n?

Tags: number-theory

What I mean by this is..

Lets say n = 4.

Then we will make a list of all powers of 3 and 6 in order until the list contains 4 integers.

We end up with [1 (shared by both 6 and 3), 3, 6, 9]

So the proportion is 3/2 (3 to 6)

Is there a formula to signify this in respect to n?

[image]

Subtract 1 from the Y vaules.

Here I can see that as we get to higher numbers, the ratio of powers of 3 to powers of 6 stabilises around 1.6. But is there an exact formula to tell us how many powers of 6 or 3 there are using n?

Another example since I believe the question was misunderstood:

[1, 3, 6, 9, 27, 36, 81, 216, 243, 729, 1296, 2187, 6561, 7776, 19683] <- This is a set of 15 integers (n), out of which 6 numbers are powers of 6. (1, 6, 36, 216, 1296, 7776)

So the answer can't be Log6(x)+1 because that is equal to around 2.5

Comment: That was my own quuestion. That was regarding how many powers of 3 are there smaller than 6^n. This is completely different.

Comment: Sorry about that. I misread your question to not realize you're asking about the sum of such powers up to $n$, not the actual number for a given $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the answer. This is the amount of powers of 6 in a set of N ordered integers. To get the amount of powers of 3, subtract the equation below from N

$$\lceil\frac{x*log_6 x}{log_3 x * log_6 x}\rceil$$

Comment: Can anyone confirm the validity of this? It seems to work well.

Comment: Verified by a professor of math.

Comment: is the ceiling over the numerator only?

Comment: No, the entire fraction

Answer (score 2):

The number of powers of $6$ in the the first $n$ integers is given by $\lfloor 
\log_6x\rfloor+1$.

If you don't want to include $1$ as  a power of $6$, remove the $+1$.

Similarly, the number of powers of $3$ in the first $n$ integers are $\lfloor 
\log_3x\rfloor+1$.

Divide these two quantities to get your ratio.

Comment: In addition, I don't see how the ratio stabilizes at 2.6.

Comment: Take 800 for example, arbitrary. There are 4 lesser powers of 6, being 1,6,36,216, and 7 lesser powers of 3, being 1,3,9,27,81,243, and 729. This leads to a ratio of 7/4. I notice that the ratio seems to converge to 1.6

Comment: This is because log6 / log3 = 1.63

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. In the first 15 integers of the ordered sequence/set, a power of 6 appears 6 times including 1.

[1, 3, 6, 9, 27, 36, 81, 216, 243, 729, 1296, 2187, 6561, 7776, 19683] <- 15 integers ordered by size, out of which 6 are powers of 6

Comment: Well, even in that, you have 9 powers of 3 and 6 powers of 6, and 9/6 = 1.5, which is closer to 1.6 than to 2.6

Comment: I agree. My proprotion is wrong because I forgot to subtract 1 in my statistic. But the question is more about how to get the amount of powers of 6 or 3 based on N

Comment: so one way is log6 of n. let's say that you're looking at N=217. log 6 is like 3.01 or something, just slightly greater than 3. this means that 6^3.01 = 217, and if you take the floor of 3.01, you get 3. sooooo there are 3 powers of 6 that are less than 217.

Comment: in a similar manner, the number of powers of 3 less than 217 is given by log3 of 217, and thats how i derived that fraction

Comment: That's the thing though. I'm not asking for the amount of powers of 3 smaller than N. I'm asking for the amount of powers of 3 (or 6) in a SET of N integers. If N = 10, there are 10 numbers. Not one number 10, but 10 numbers. As in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. But instead, these numbers are powers of 3 and 6 ordered from smallest to biggest. So you take all powers of 3 and 6, and keep generating the numbers in order from smallest to biggest, until you count that you have generated N numbers. Then you try to find out how many of those numbers are powers of 6. (or 3)

Comment: ahh i see. thank you for the clarification @TiboroJacko